# After attempted PSU replacement PC keeps booting into BIOS

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I've bought Asus 2080Ti graphics card and turned out my old PSU can't support it, only one PCIE cable while the card needs 2. So I've bought Corsair RM750 PSU, installed everything and booted my PC. It booted into BIOS. I've returned my old graphics card - Gigabyte 1060 - still booting into BIOS. I've returned my old PSU - still nothing but BIOS. Clearing CMOS didn't help. It keeps booting into BIOS no matter what. Tried switching SATA cables, different SATA ports on the MB, nothing helps, the PC keeps booting into BIOS even with the old configuration.
Specs:
2x WD 2Tb drives
MB ASUS Prime 8250M-C
Graphics Card: Gigabyte 1060 or ASUS 2080Ti ROG

basically, after PSU replacement the PC stopped booting even if everything is restored to the old working configuration. No idea what went wrong there.

P.S. Not sure it's relevant, but the new PSU is modular.

Comment: Will it boot from USB, e.g., Live Ubuntu? If so, you've an issue with SSD/HDD.

Comment: When it boots into BIOS does all your other hardware show up? Booting to BIOS sounds like a boot drive configuration issue instead of anything to do with the GPU

Comment: I see the CPU and HDDs. Everything looks normal, no errors.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It boots to Windows installation USB, but the installation fails because it says media drivers are missing. But when I use option to browse to search the drivers, I can see all data on my HDDs.